# Text wrap in html c#

Tags: c#, html, word-wrap

I'm struggling to make my text wrap in my application. 
I need to send an email with information from one dataTable. I am building a string with a html table to be sent. My problem is that some information in cells is really long. I need a solution so I can wrap it.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr bgcolor='#D6D6D6'>");

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
                sb.AppendFormat("<td text-wrap='normal'>{0}</td>" + tab, cellValue);
    }

    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
}
```

I have tried text-wrap, and word-wrap but it doesn't work.
If you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: Try wrapping the text in a `<p>{0}</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html is not well formed.

you can either add a class to is like so

```
<td class="myClass">....</td>
```

then create a class like so

```
.myClass{
white-space:normal;
}
```

or put it in a style tag

```
<td style="text-wrap:normal;">{0}</td>"
```

or `<td style="white-space:normal;">{0}</td>"`

Comment: i have tried with style="..", but it doesn't work either.. and to create a style .myClass an use it after.. i dont know where to create it.. my html code is composed ic c#.. sholut i concatenate another string containing the style in front of my table?

Comment: to create a class you would create a new folder for ease of reference, create a myCssFile.css and put the class in there, then you would reference it in your aspx page.  I don't want to sound rude, but how new are you to web development as it would appear that youre missing some fundamentals

Comment: yes, i have a year working with c#.. wind forms app, wpf app, asp.. small applications.. i'm not the best at coding, but i'm trying.. this is a wpf application.. in aspx i know how to do this thing, but in wpf i have no clue :)

Comment: WPF are desktop applications using XAML, is this a desktop or a web application youre building?

Comment: this is a desktop application

Comment: ok, then you need to look at this link which will help you apply your style to the XAML. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.style

Comment: i made it, it was somewhere else the problem.. it works with text-wrap:  normal.. no need for style or something :) thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the text on a website or html-based document,
you could use break-line/-row:

```
String text = "First row <br />Second row <br />...";
```

`<br />` is basically the new line character `\n` in html.

Comment: i was thinking about this.. my string is a paragraph. i was thinking at every 5 line spaces to insert a <br /> tag, but is extra work.. i thought is there a easier way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add width value on your table column and apparently it will fix your problem. :)